# Add Tab to Homebox

Tags: routes, dashboard

I'd love to create a tabbed display for my Homebox where each tab is it's own Homebox. So for instance:

> Dashboard    Timesheet    Analytics

Where each of the tabs is a link to an individual Homebox - Dashboard being the main menu item.

Comment: I ended up using Panels Everywhere to override the main Homebox page and added tabs to a row before the content.

Answer (score 1):

There is module for that: [Quick Tabs](https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs)

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content, specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with corresponding content. Clicking on the tabs makes the corresponding content display instantly, using jQuery

Comment: Quicktabs doesn't seem to work well with Homebox. I'm not able to switch tabs effectively. Trying some more, though.

Comment: I ended up using Panels Everywhere. This way I have complete control over everything on the page. Quick Tabs didn't work.